# mechanize submit again next page

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if anyone had tips on how to submit twice? I can verify that it is submitting the form but I need to submit again on the following confirmation page. Is this possible?

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://internal/test/stopservice.cfm")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['Account_number'] = 'Enter your Name'
br.form['Name_first_account'] = 'Enter your Title'
br.form['Name_last_account'] = 'Enter your message'

br.form['Address_House_Number_stop'] = 'Enter your message'
br.form['Address_Direction_Prefix_stop'] = ['E']
br.form['Address_Street_stop'] = 'Enter your message'
br.form['City_stop'] = 'Enter your message'
br.form['State_stop'] = ['IL']
br.form['Zip_mail_stop'] = '60062'
br.form['E_mail'] = 'test@gmail.com'
br.form['Requester_Type'] = ['Tenant']
br.form['confirm_email'] = 'Enter your message'
br.form['Phone_Contact_1'] = '111'
br.form['Phone_Contact_2'] = '555'
br.form['phone_Contact_3'] = '9999'
br.form['MM_stop'] = ['09']
br.form['DD_stop'] = ['22']
br.form['YYYY_stop'] = ['2017']
br.find_control("Turn_off_Gas").items[0].selected=True
br.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mechanize

url = "..."

def on_start(url):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(url)
    return br

def sub_form(br):
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['Account_number'] = 'Enter your Name'
    # other options....
    new_url = br.submit()
    # retrieve the new url after submiting the form
    br.open(new_url.geturl())
    # complete the new form
    br.select_form(nr=...)
    # other options here
    br.submit()

# initialize the browser
browsr = on_start(url)
sub_form(browsr)
```